# wordpress how can i get the title of the previous or next page?

Tags: wordpress

How can I get the title of the previous page with get_the_title with wordpress?

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: Do you want the title, or a link. If a link consider this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/next-page-not-next-post/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [get_next_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) and [get_prev_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post)

See [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) page for complete list.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get my previous page title:

```
$prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
$str = file_get_contents($prev_url);
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str));
preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title);
$prev_page_title = $title[1];
echo $prev_page_title;
```